# Inject route data using middleware

Tags: asp.net-core, middleware

I'm building a very simple rest api. All my endpoints under a specific controller requires an object of type QueryContext. This object is a "simplified" version of HttpRequest.

Currently, I use a factory accepting an HttpRequest and returning a object of type QueryContext.

```
public interface IQueryContextFactory
{
    QueryContext Create(string query, HttpRequest request);
}

internal class HttpRequestQueryContextFactory : IQueryContextFactory
{
    public QueryContext Create(string query, HttpRequest request)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(query))
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(query));
        if (request == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(request));

        return new QueryContext
        {
            Method = request.Method,
            QueryString = string.Concat(query, request.QueryString),
            Parameters = request.Query.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value.ToString().Replace("\"", string.Empty)),
            Headers = request.Headers.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value.ToString())
        };
    }
}
```

Then i call this factory from my endpoint

```
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Process(string query)
    {
        (...)
        var ctx = _contextFactory.Create(query, Request);
    }
```

Is this recommended to use a middleware to add the QueryContext to the route data? This i would be able to get it as a parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can inject a IQueryContextFactory in your API Controller.

Here's an example:

```
[Route("api/my")]
public class MyController : Controller {

    private readonly IQueryContextFactory QueryContextFactory;

    public MyController(IQueryContextFactory queryContextFactory) {
      if (queryContextFactory == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(queryContextFactory));
      QueryContextFactory = queryContextFactory;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Get(string query) {
      var ctx = QueryContextFactory.Create(query, Request);
      return Ok();
    }
}
```

Then, you configure the injection in your `Startup.cs` like this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
  //...
  services.AddSingleton<IQueryContextFactory, HttpRequestQueryContextFactory>();
  //...
}
```

You can find more info about injection [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection).

Comment: I will for this approach as it's easier to unit test!

Answer (score 0):

As you have shown, all the data in your simplified QueryContext class is also in the HttpContext. Rather than injecting another object into you controller you could do a couple of different things.

1. Initialize a QueryContext property or field your controller's constructor. That way it is available to all your controller methods without having to duplicate code.
2. Rather add a new class extend HttpContext class with some extension methods that do what you want.

Comment: If you extend HttpContext is this still easy to unit test?

Comment: Well it is really easy to test the HttpContext extension methods but that's probably not your question. When it comes down to unit testing controllers I suspect the answer is no.  In pretty much all the applications I work with in MVC the context affects controllers in more ways than is being described in the initial post.... think about the [Authorize] tag. A façade around the HttpContext doesn't give a general solution. I would test using a mocked out WebHost instead. That way I could fake out HttpContext completely, including injecting other things, like DbContext...